# How to have the same rectangle?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, size

I have 2 different rectangles, I want the same size like 'Máscara'.

I know that the image have different size. For that reason I want the same rectangle independently the image size.

[image]

This is my code

**css**

```
.bann-bottom p {
font-size: 1.4em;
color:#fff;
margin: 0.3em 0em 0em 0em;
}
.bann-bottom {
 padding: 18em 0em 0em 0em;
 }

.bann-head {
float: left;
width: 19.5%;
padding: 2em 0em 2em 0em;
margin: 0% 0.5% 0% 0%;
background:#FFFFFF; 
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="banner">
<div class="container">
    <div class="banner-main">
      <h1>La mejor tienda de Snorkel de Mallorca</h1>
      <div class="bann-bottom">
        <div class="bann-head">
            <a href="http://www.marca.com"><img src="images/mascara.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" height="500" width="300"></a>
                <h3><a  href="http://www.marca.com"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Máscaras</button> </a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="bann-head">
                <a href="http://www.marca.com"><img src="images/tubo.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" height="500" width="1000"></a>
                <h3><a  href="http://www.marca.com"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Tubos</button> </a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bannhead` is taking the width of the elements contained inside it.

Hence as you already knew it is taking the width and height of the image itself.

If you want both of them to be of same `height`, then give `bannhead` a fixed height like:

```
.bann-head {
 float: left;
 height: 300px;
 width: 19.5%;
 padding: 2em 0em 2em 0em;
 margin: 0% 0.5% 0% 0%;
 background:#FFFFFF; 
}
```

and **[object-fit](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)**

```
bannhead img{
  height: 200px;/*change this accordingly*/
  object-fit: cover;/* fill; contain;*/
}
```

and the images will adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! with the height, the rectangles are already perfectly placed. For the size of the images I use the style and I am doing well :)

Answer (score 2):

A way to do this is to use a `background-image` on a div and set `background-size: contain`.

This way you then specify the height of the div, so that they will all be the same and `background-size: contain` will then fit the background images in to  the best of its abilities (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Here's your code, slightly modified to show this. You may need to make some more changes (e.g., you'll probably have to mess around with the `<a>` tags to make them behave how you want)

HTML

```
<div class="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="banner-main">
      <h1>La mejor tienda de Snorkel de Mallorca</h1>
      <div class="bann-bottom">
        <a href="http://www.marca.com">
          <div class="bann-head" id="mascara">
            <h3>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Máscaras</button>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="bann-head" id="tubo">
            <h3>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Tubos</button>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.bann-bottom p {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color:#fff;
  margin: 0.3em 0em 0em 0em;
}

.bann-bottom {
   padding: 18em 0em 0em 0em;
 }

.bann-head {
  float: left;
  width: 19.5%;
  padding: 2em 0em 2em 0em;
  margin: 0% 0.5% 0% 0%;
  background:#FFFFFF;
  height: 13%; /* You can change this to whatever looks best */
  background-size: contain;
}

#mascara{
  background-image: url('images/mascara.jpg');
}

#tubo{
  background-image: url('images/tubo.jpg');
}
```